# Interpolation Methods for Contours Plotted in CartoPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, interpolation, cartopy

I am using matplotlib and Cartopy to generate images from a 2-D gridded dataset. An example looks as follows in the following link:

[image]

Key code that drives this image creation, and will come into question is as follows:

```
dataset = Dataset('/pathtofile/' + ymd + '/file_d0tmax.nc')
temp = dataset.variables['TMAX2M'][:]
lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
ax = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.95, 0.9],projection=crs.LambertConformal())
ax.set_adjustable('datalim')
#WPTZ DMA
ax.set_extent([-74.890000, -70.890000, 42.680000, 45.380000], crs=crs.LambertConformal())

im = plt.contourf(lons, lats, temp, levels=vals, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, transform=crs.LambertConformal())

plt.colorbar(im, pad=0.05, ticks=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100])
```

The filled contour generates successfully, however in particular areas, the filled contours appear jagged, or splotchy. Is there a better alternative than contourf() to produce a smoother interpolation?

Comment: What about using more `vals`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want genuine interpolation, then `contourf()` is best, especially with more values as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggests.  However, you could try a `pcolormesh()` instead, which samples each point instead of interpolating between them.  I can't imagine it would be any better though; I'd go for more values so you get a smoother interpolation.

Comment: Thank you both, honestly, an idea that I did not consider prior to this post. For clarity, this is what I currently have for defined values, would it help to define these values at every 0.5?: `vals=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]`

Answer (score 1):

> "jagged or splotchy"

I'm seeing little diamonds, which I guess are single points with a value significantly different from their neighbours.

In that context these contours are the "right" answer that respects the data.

In general, any plot will respect the data given, so for smoother visuals you will need to process the data itself somehow, in this case you need *either* finer resolution (each datapoint appears bigger), *or* less detail (fewer points).

You can downscale your data somehow (ideally not just sub-sampling, but that does work !), alternatively some local averaging like

```
b = 0.25 * (a[::2, ::2] + a[::2, 1::2] + a[1::2, ::2] + a[1::2, 1::2])
```

(I know, a bit nasty and doesn't scale !)
For nice visuals results, you can leave it at the existing resolution (or even upscale) but explicitly smooth it, e.g. with a rolling window average.